# cross origin requests from chrome extension mv3 web accessible resource html

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Based on this [blog post](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches/), in chrome extension mv3, cross origin requests initiated from content script are disallowed but it also mentioned that "Extension pages, such as background pages, popups, or options pages, are unaffected by this change".

But how about the cross origin requests initiated from the an a static html page (listed under `web_accessible_resources`)? I saw it is also blocked, any ways to bypass the check for this case?

Comment: web_accessible_resources iframe has the same permissions as the background script, so if you see the error it's either a bug in Chrome or your extension doesn't have the request's origin in `host_permissions`.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks! adding host urls to "host_permissions" works!